# How do you cache sdkmanager in AzureDevops?

Tags: android, caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I do the following in my pipeline

```
          - bash: |
              $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'ndk;20.0.5594570' >/dev/null
              $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'ndk;21.0.6113669' >/dev/null
            displayName: "install NDK"
```

Which takes about 3 minutes

I was wondering if I can cache this to speed things up.  However, I am not sure where it puts the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a previous answer, the `Cache@2` task is supposed to be used.  And as per the comment path where the ndk is downloaded to is in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.  The thing to note is ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is not a variable that is immediately accessible.  It needs to be exposed.

So to put it all together with a working example:

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ANDROID_SDK_ROOT;]$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'ndk | "$(Agent.OS)"'
    path: $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/ndk

- bash: |
    $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'ndk;20.0.5594570' >/dev/null
    $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager 'ndk;21.0.6113669' >/dev/null
  displayName: "install NDK"
```

This technique can be used in other places so that you'd get an agent pool agnostic script where the files are places in the home directory.  Applies to both `macOS` and `ubuntu` pools.

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HOME_DIRECTORY;]$HOME"
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'gradlew | "$(Agent.OS)"'
    # this won't work on macOS
    # path: /home/vsts/.gradle/wrapper
    # but this will
    path: $(HOME_DIRECTORY)/.gradle/wrapper
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"'
    path: $(HOME_DIRECTORY)/.gradle/caches
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to cache ndk. You may check Pipeline caching:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops

Caching is added to a pipeline using the [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/cache?view=azure-devops). Pipeline caching can help reduce build time by allowing the outputs or downloaded dependencies from one run to be reused in later runs, thereby reducing or avoiding the cost to recreate or redownload the same files again. Caching is especially useful in scenarios where the same dependencies are downloaded over and over at the start of each run.

Comment: The problem we have is "where is NDK downloaded being stored"?  That way I can add it in.

Comment: You could list the installed and available packages with command `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager '--list'`. The location is supposed to be `ndk/20.0.5594570/ ` and `ndk/21.0.6113669/`.

Comment: Yes but your answer leaves a few problems.

Comment: Could you please indicate it or modify it?