# How to cache Android NDK in Azure devops pipeline?

Tags: android, azure-devops, android-ndk, azure-pipelines

While creating a task in Azure devops pipeline, I am requred to cache the NDK to reduce the build time. Hence, I am trying to write a task for the same.

For example here is what I am using for caching the gradle and konan repos

```
variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.gradle
  KONAN_USER_HOME: /Users/runner/.konan

steps:
  - bash: env
    displayName: env vars

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      restoreKeys: gradle
      path: $(GRADLE_USER_HOME)
    displayName: Gradle build cache

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'konan | "$(Agent.OS)" | cache'
      restoreKeys: konan
      path: $(KONAN_USER_HOME)
    displayName: Konan build cache
```

they work just fine!

But for NDK, how do I know the **relative repository path for my NDK** and cache it, assuming the task will be something like this

```
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'ndk | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      restoreKeys: ndk
      path: $(NDK_PATH)
    displayName: NDK build cache
```

Any help in this is highly helpful.

Comment: nice, it seems ndk is already part of the env. vars

Comment: Thanks @sallah let look for env vars from the devops setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured this out, forgot to post here and this is what I found.
1 - to get the relative path of android-ndk from devops setup (I dont have those permissions).
2 -  Then run the caching task to cache into that path

1 - get relative env vars with this bash output. [CREDITS](https://djangocas.dev/blog/pass-variable-in-azure-devops-pipelines/) So In steps I write:

```
steps:
  - bash: env
    displayName: env vars
```

prints all the env variables available [example gist with some vars intentionally removed](https://gist.github.com/sud007/4692933cae6275272fd504424bd29d54)
from that I picked up the path relevant to my use

```
2021-01-19T16:17:44.4273060Z ANDROID_HOME=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk

2021-01-19T16:17:44.4276800Z ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk

2021-01-19T16:17:44.4320010Z ANDROID_NDK_18R_PATH=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045

2021-01-19T16:17:44.4328690Z ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

now the most relevant path was to `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` as this makes sense to then append `/ndk` to it.

then comes my task

2 the caching task:

- create variable for path `NDK_HOME: /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk`

and add it in the cache task which completely looks like this

```
variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.gradle
  KONAN_USER_HOME: /Users/runner/.konan
  NDK_HOME: /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

name: $(date:yyyy).$(Month)$(rev:.r)

steps:
  - bash: env
    displayName: env vars

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      restoreKeys: gradle
      path: $(GRADLE_USER_HOME)
    displayName: Gradle build cache

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'konan | "$(Agent.OS)" | cache'
      restoreKeys: konan
      path: $(KONAN_USER_HOME)
    displayName: Konan build cache

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'ndk | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      restoreKeys: ndk
      path: $(NDK_HOME)/ndk
    displayName: NDK build cache
```

Works like a charm

**One other way** to dynamically create your variable [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711727). Thank you
then my task looks like

```
steps:
  - bash: env
    displayName: env vars

  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ANDROID_SDK_ROOT;]$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'ndk | "$(Agent.OS)"'
      restoreKeys: ndk
      path: $(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)/ndk
    displayName: NDK build cache
```

works in same manner

Comment: How I can tell my pipeline to use an specific version? How do I install it?

Comment: @Otto Cheley answer to your question is 
Add below task in your job

- task: Bash@3
        displayName: Install NDK
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.4.7075529"

Comment: Correct @MuhammadWaqas for specific version there is a task that needs to be created.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know the relative repository path for my NDK?

You can use the environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_PATH` to get the path for the NDK.

If you are using the ndk that pre-installed in Microsoft hosted agent `windows-latest`, the value of `ANDROID_NDK_PATH` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle`.

Comment: yeah but this could not answer the complete solution. thanks I figured that. it was not easy to get the env var paths without knowing the system configuration itself. And I did not have access to that machine setup.